# Setting new alias in PowerShell getting error

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm trying to set new alias for creating a new file in Powershell. I'm using the following line to set an alias.

```
New-Alias touch New-Item ItemType file
```

But I'm getting the error saying:

> ***New-Alias: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ItemType'***

Answer (score 2):

Aliases in PowerShell cannot have parameters as part of the alias - that is, you can make `touch` an alias for `New-Item`, but you still have to use it as though you were using `New-Item`. If you want to incorporate parameters into an "alias", or define an alternate syntax, you have to write a function instead.